# silverlight listbox inside checkbox?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I need to get how many checkboxes are checked in listbox. Do you have some idea how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit item template for ListBox and add checkbox for item.
In that case you also can add event handler for checkboxes and handel check event.
Or if you are adding checkboxes by code than add handler for event and then add checkboxes.
Hope this will help you.